# Left-/right-translate of a two-form

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, poisson-geometry

The context is that of coboundary Lie bialgebras discussed in 
["Lie bialgebras, Poisson Lie groups and dressing transformations"](http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/cmat/kosmann/lnp2.pdf) by Y. Kosmann-Schwarzbach.

In section 4.2, she defines objects like $r^\rho$ and $r^\lambda$ where $r$ is an element of $\Lambda^2\frak g$ and the superscripts $\rho$ and $\lambda$ should stand for the right - and left-translates of the element $r$ that we could write as
$$r= \sum_{i,j} r_{ij}T_i\wedge T_j  \,,$$
for $T_i$ a basis of the Lie algebra $\frak g$.

However I can't find any explantation to what this notation, e $r^{\lambda/\rho}$, actually means...

On a group element $h$ the left and right translation are evident:
$$\lambda_g(h)=gh\,, \quad \rho_g(h)=hg,$$

where $g,h$ are in the connected Lie group whose algebra is $\frak g$. But I don't understand how a left- or right-translation is actually computed for a two-form like above.

---

EDIT:

More handson I would like to understand how for example the Poisson structure constructed out of $r$ by
$$\pi = r^\lambda - r^\rho \,,$$
looks in terms of the decomposition of $r$ in terms of the components $r_{ij}$ and the generators $T_i$. That is can we express the components $\pi_{ij}$ i.t.o. of the group element $g$ and $r_{ij}$?

Answer (score 1):

What is meant is that you defined the action of $r$ on general tangent vectors by tranlating the vectors to the neutral element via a left or right translation. So for $g\in G$ and tangent vectors $\xi,\eta\in T_gG$, one puts
\begin{gather}
r^{\lambda}(g)(\xi,\eta):=r(T_g\lambda_{g^{-1}}\cdot\xi,T_g\lambda_{g^{-1}}\cdot\eta))\\
r^{\rho}(g)(\xi,\eta):=r(T_g\rho_{g^{-1}}\cdot\xi,T_g\rho_{g^{-1}}\cdot\eta)).
\end{gather}

Comment: @Andres Cap Thanks that already helps! But I would like to understand how the action of $g$ can be expressed at the level of the components rather than in abstract notation. I added a more detailed question above. Thanks in advance!